# Arduino Button Bouncing

Tags: c++, button

What is my Issue with the button, it dont work correctly and I am wondering why. I dont get it. The Button is connected over the 5V Then a 10k resistor and connected with a wire to the ground. I think the isr is correctly implemented. And the function is also correct. But I do not really get whats the issue with the Button is. I tried a capacitor but that didnt also work well... I connected it directly before the the button.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12);


unsigned long volatile startTime = 0;
unsigned long volatile endTime = 0;
unsigned long volatile  sec;
volatile boolean buttonState;
const int button = 2;
long ms;
long timeT;
long z;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Stopwatch");


  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button), isr, FALLING);

}

void loop() {


  if (buttonState == LOW) {

    startTime = millis();
  }

  while (buttonState == HIGH) {


    z = (millis() - startTime);
    sec = (z / 1000);
    ms = z % 1000;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(sec);
    lcd.print(".");
    lcd.print(ms);
    lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
    lcd.print("Secs");

  }

}
//Interrupt Service Routines
void isr() {
  buttonState = !buttonState;
}
```

Comment: *"it dont work correctly"* is not a precise description of a problem

Comment: @MatG thanks for the reminder. I meant by this the button in my program. precisely the push button did not recognized the pushes correctly for example if it was pushed a few times, the button, was not doing the stop or start.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are quirky things. It can happen that they send multiple signals (rather, that the contact isn't immediately stable). A condenser might help, but that too can output a wavy signal and trigger multiple "events" and, anyway, it introduces a delay.

So, delay for delay, you could do something like this which should be more controllable:

```
if (buttonState !== previousState) {
    startTime = millis();
    previousState = buttonState;
    triggered = 0;
} else {
    if (0 == triggered) {
        if ((millis() - startTime) > threshold) {
            triggered = 1;
            // Okay, buttonState is now reliably LOW or HIGH
            ...
        }
    } else {
        // Continuous event (pressed or not-pressed)
    }
}
```

In practice, this should only react when the button has been uninterruptedly pressed or released for "threshold" millis. Assuming BTN is the actual signal from the button without any other attending hardware,

```
                   1        2    3                     4       5   6
BTN: LLLLLLLLLLLLLLHLHHLHHHLHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHLHHHLLHHLLLLLLLLL
FLT: ___________________________-----------------------------------_____
Time --------------------------------------------------------------->

1 button is physically pressed
2 button is now truly pressed
3 stable button press is detected
4 button begins to be released
5 button is now fully released
6 stable button release is detected
```